# Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of all complex $2^n$th roots of unity, $n=0, 1, 2,\dots$. Prove that [. . .] every subgroup is marginal.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, roots-of-unity, combinatorial-group-theory

This is part of **Exercise 2.3.3** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Every%20subgroup%20is%20marginal%2C%20Complex&p=8), it is new to MSE. However, the first part of the exercise is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512920/104041).

### The Details:

On page 57 of Robinson's book:

> If $W$ is a set of words in $x_1, x_2, \dots$ and $G$ is any group, a normal subgroup $N$ is said to be *$W$-marginal* in $G$ if
>
> $$w(g_1,\dots, g_{i-1}, g_ia, g_{i+1},\dots, g_r)=w(g_1,\dots, g_{i-1}, g_i, g_{i+1},\dots, g_r)$$
>
> for all $g_i\in G, a\in N$ and all $w(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_r)$ in $W$. This is equivalent to the requirement: $g_i\equiv h_i \mod N, (1\le i\le r)$, always implies that $w(g_1,\dots, g_r)=w(h_1,\dots, h_r)$.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of all complex $2^n$th roots of unity, $n=0, 1, 2,\dots$. Prove that [. . .] every subgroup is marginal.

### Thoughts:

With respect to what collection of words $W$ is each subgroup of $G$? Would it be (some union of) $$W_m=\{x_1^{2^m}\}$$ for some $m\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$? I don't yet know where to go from here.

---

The exercise is at the end of the chapter  on free groups and presentations, and, since I am studying for a postgraduate research degree in combinatorial group theory, it concerns me that I can’t do it yet.

---

A related concept is that of a *verbal subgroup*; indeed, the first part of the exercise is about them. I have encountered these before in, say, Magnus *et al.*'s, *"Combinatorial Group Theory: [. . .]"*.

---

The type of answer I am looking for is a detailed hint or a full solution, with an eye to understanding marginal subgroups in general.

---

Please help :)

Comment: In an abelian group, the verbal subgroups all correspond to a word of the form $x^k$. See, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512920/verbal-subgroups-of-the-group-of-all-2nth-roots-of-unity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is an abelian group, then its verbal subgroups are of the form $W(G)$ where $W=\{x^m\}$ for some nonnegative integer $m$. For example, this follows from B.H. Neumann’s old result that every group word is equivalent to a commutator word and a power word. You can see a sketch of that argument [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3907706/verbal-subgroups-of-mathbbz2). Now, because the Prüfer groups are divisible, that means that they are verbally simple: the only verbal subgroups are the whole group and the trivial group.

What is the marginal subgroup associated to the word $w(x)=x^m$? It consists precisely of the elements $z\in G$ such that $w(x)=w(zx)=w(xz)$. That means, since $G$ is abelian, that we must have
$$x^m = z^mx^m=x^mz^m$$
which means that the marginal subgroup of $G$ associated to $w(x)=x^m$ consists precisely of $\{z\in G\mid z^m=e\}$.

Here, every proper subgroup of $G$ is finite and cyclic of order a power of $2$. Thus, the subgroup of order $2^k$ will be precisely the marginal subgroup associated to $x^{2^k}$. The whole group corresponds to the marginal subgroup associated to $x^0$.

When $m$ is relatively prime to $2$, you get the elements that satisfy $x^m=e$, which is just the trivial group.

---

Marginal subgroups in general are a bit tricky. The $i$th marginal group associated to the word $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, $w_i^*(G)$ consists of the $z\in G$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
w(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_i,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n) &= 
w(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},zx_i,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)\\
&= w(x_1,\ldots,x_{-1},x_iz,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n).
\end{align*}$$
The marginal subgroup associated to $w$ is then $\cap_{i=1}^n w_i^*(G)$. Even Philip Hall messed it up at one point: his initial paper introducing marginal subgroups says that the marginal subgroup associated to $w(x,y)=[x,y]$ is the center (true), and that the marginal subgroup associated to $w(x)=x^n$ consists of the central elements of exponent $n$; but this is not necessarily true, since if $G$ is of exponent $n$, then the marginal subgroup is everything (since the verbal subgroup is trivial).

But for abelian groups, since every word amounts to a power word $x^k$, it will just be the elements of exponent $k$. So the marginal subgroups of an abelian group $G$ are precisely the subgroups $G_{(k)} = \{g\in G\mid g^k=e\}$.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the view that *"[m]arginal subgroups in general are a bit tricky"*. It's reassuring that it's not just me struggling with them . . .

Comment: @Shaun: At least I find them tricky.... even after 25 years of knowing about them.