# Show that the group of all complex $2^n$th roots of unity, $n=0,1,2,...$, has a fully-invariant subgroup which is not verbal

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, roots-of-unity, combinatorial-group-theory, verbal-subgroups

This is the last part of **Exercise 2.3.3** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. The following are the other parts.

1. [Verbal subgroups of the group of all $2^n$th roots of unity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512920/104041)
2. [Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of all complex $2^n$th roots of unity, $n=0, 1, 2,\dots$. Prove that [. . .] every subgroup is marginal.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4099900/104041)

### The Details:

On page 28 of Robinson's book, slightly edited, is:

> A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be *fully-invariant* if $\alpha (H)\le H$ for all $\alpha \in{\rm End}(G)$.

Here ${\rm End}(G)$ is the set of all *endomorphisms* of $G$; that is, all homomorphisms from $G$ to $G$.

On page 56 *ibid.*,

> Let $F$ be a free group on a countably infinite set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ and let $W$ be a nonempty subset of $G$. If $w=x_{i_1}^{l_1}\dots x_{i_r}^{l_r}\in W$ and $g_1,\dots, g_r$ are elements of a group $G$, we define the *value* of the word $w$ at $(g_1,\dots,g_r)$ to be $w(g_1,\dots,g_r)=g_1^{l_1}\dots g_{r}^{l_r}$. The subgroup of $G$ generated by all values in $G$ of words in $W$ is called the *verbal subgroup* of $G$ determined by $W$,
>
> $$W(G)=\langle w(g_1,g_2,\dots) \mid g_i\in G, w\in W\rangle.$$

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of all complex $2^n$th roots of unity, $n=0,1,2,\dots$. [. . .] Show [. . .] that $G$ has a fully-invariant subgroup which is not verbal.

### Thoughts:

By part (1) of the exercise, it would be sufficient to find a nontrivial, proper subgroup of $G$ that is fully-invariant.

The subgroup cannot be cyclic${}^\dagger$ but, since $G$ is abelian, it must be abelian as well.

Beyond these simple observations, I'm stuck.

### Further Context:

As I said in my question on part (2): the exercise is at the end of the chapter of Robinson's book about presentations and free groups; so, basically, it's about combinatorial group theory; and my postgraduate studies are in & around that discipline.

The type of answer I'm looking for is not just a naming of the subgroup. I want to understand as much as possible. I would like to know what thought processes went into finding the subgroup.

Please help  :)

---

$\dagger$: *From the comments . . .* My reasoning is that the order of a cyclic subgroup of $G$ would be a power of two, say $2^m$, so that $W=\{ x^{2^m}\}$ would make it verbal . . .

Comment: Why can't the subgroup be cyclic?

Comment: That's a good question, @Wojowu. Thank you. My reasoning is that the order of a cyclic subgroup of $G$ would be a power of two, say $2^m$, so that $W=\{ x^{2^m}\}$ would make it verbal . . . I think.

Comment: You are getting turned around. The verbal subgroup corresponding to $x^{2^m}$ is the subgroup generated by the set of *values* the word takes, so it would be generated/equal to all elements of the form $g^{2^m}$. By contrast, the subgroup would be all elements such that $w(g)=1$, which is *not* the verbal subgroup of $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [we've discussed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512920/verbal-subgroups-of-the-group-of-all-2nth-roots-of-unity/3512949#3512949) [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099900/let-g-be-the-multiplicative-group-of-all-complex-2nth-roots-of-unity-n-0), the verbal subgroups correspond to words $x^m$, and since this group is divisible, the only verbal subgroups are the trivial (when $m=0$), and the whole group (when $m\neq 0$).

So this question is really just asking you to find a proper nontrivial subgroup that is fully invariant.

The proper subgroups are precisely the subgroups of the form
$$H_n = \{x\in G \mid x^{2^n}=e\}$$
for $n=0,1,\ldots$, with the proper nontrivial ones being those with $n\neq 0$.

Note that if $x\in H_n$ and $\varphi\colon G\to G$, then $e = \varphi(x^{2^n}) = (\varphi(x))^{2^n}$, hence $\varphi(x)\in H_n$.

So all of the subgroups are fully invariant.

---

You got turned around with the definition of verbal subgroup. The verbal subgroup associated to $w(x)=x^k$ is the subgroup generated by all *values* of the word. that is, it would be $G^{k} = \{g^k\mid g\in G\}$, rather than the set $\{x\in G\mid w(x)=1\}$.

(A subgroup for which $w(x)=1$ for all $x$ would of course lie in the variety determined by $w$, in this case, "groups of exponent $k$")

Note that in any group $G$, for any $k\gt 0$, the subgroup generated by all elements of exponent $k$ is fully invariant, by the argument above.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected what I think was a typo. Am I right?

Comment: @Shaun: Yes; thank you.